# How does Airflow integration with Kerberos work?

Tags: airflow, kerberos

We are using Airflow 2.0.1 with following settings:

- celery executor and 4 workers on 4 nodes.
- most of our tasks run some Hadoop applications launched via BashOperator
- using impersonation
- using just default queue

Firstly, we setup an own job that renewed the Kerberos tickets of run_as_user users. For about week it worked fine, then one of worker started to fail with missing Kerberos ticket. We could not find any changes between last successful run and the failing jobs; there was a valid ticket on the node; so we stopped the worker. Next day, we restarted the Airflow completely and missing Kerberos ticket was reported by all the workers. Temporarily, we are able to run the jobs with one worker when the kinit is run inside the DAGs and going to enable Kerberos according to https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/security/kerberos.html?highlight=kerberos.

The questions would be

- if anybody could describe in more detail, how the Airflow integration with Kerberos works
- why the ticket used from command line is not seen when we launch an application via BashOperator

Comment: Looks like the source code is there, have fun...
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/security/kerberos.py

Comment: It would have been a good idea to post the **logs** from that "Kerberos renewer". Or to mention the lack of logs, which would be an interesting fact (the log patterns are in the source code...)

Comment: i see.. i am quite new to this, therefore i only asked such a general question... and trying to learn more meanwhile. I was looking into code i am not sure if the settings from https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/security/kerberos.html?highlight=kerberos are anyhow relevant for the BashOperator? Seems to me they are used only for the Hive and Hdfs hook, is it right?

Comment: hmm, so playing with that on test cluster, the setting affects the BashOperator

Comment: After enabling Kerberos according to documantation, it works, only seems that the cache gets too little access rights when generated by the kinit within airflow kerberos. We were getting 

getting org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

When the rights of the cache were enhanced, it worked.

Comment: Regarding my second question, why the user's ticket is not seen from Airflow task, despite it is seen from command line - cannot be because of impersonation via sudo and  use of /etc/sudoers -  as the password is not passed, the kinit is not called authomatically?

Comment: _"the cache gets too little access rights"_ >> When the ticket cache is stored in a **file** then it is not supposed to be accessed by any user except the one that issued the `kinit`. When it is stored in the Linux "keyring" or the Windows "LSA" it's even more strict since you cannot change the access privileges.

Comment: Bottom line: if your service runs under a service account, then its ticket cache should be specific to the service account and created by/accessed by the same account. When using a **file** the common practice is to suffix the file name with the UID, cf. `krb5.conf` defaults _(er, the older defaults, nowadays it's rather KEYRING by default except that Java does not support that...)_

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. I did some tests and think understand a bit better now what happened to us:

Access to hdfs from BashOperator started to fail with Kerberos error and i thought i must set configuration according to https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/security/kerberos.html?highlight=kerberos. When testing it, the worker was trying to read by run_as_user user ticket cache file configured in airflow.cfg and created by airflow kerberos  and it didnt have rights to it...

Therefore, i was checking where the tickets are stored on production and they are in /tmp of the service which runs the Airflow worker. I mean the tickets created by kinit run in BashOperators in a DAG, but our script that was renewing the tickets did ssh to all the nodes where Airflow workers run, so the tickets were stored in regular server /tmp.

The fails started some days after we launched Airflow in services. We have still a lot of kinits directly in our DAGs (as it was the way we used before, because before we used queues). With launching workers on several nodes without queues we also set up the script for renewing the ticktes (doing ssh...) to be sure the tickets are renewed on all nodes. I think the Kerberos issues occurred just after restart of services, because the tickets created by kinits in DAGs were deleted. If it is like that, the Kerberos issues would have occured also when we launched the services for the first time, but we had also other issues, so maybe we didnt notice.